# Can I make Smarty select a template from a directory based on priority?

Tags: php, templates, smarty

I'm making a PHP wiki engine that uses the same template for all websites that point to it. However some websites have a custom template. Can I make Smarty use this custom template in case it exists?

Here is my directory structure:

```
/web/wiki/templates                 <--  all templates here
/web/wiki/templates/wiki.domain.com <-- individual template
```

How can I make smarty use templates in `/web/wiki/templates/wiki.domain.com` first for `wiki.domain.com`, and if the template doesn't exist in this directory, then use the template in `/web/wiki/templates`?

Can I define multiple template directories for Smarty, and have it first try to choose template from the top directory? If I could do this, I could simply change the order of template directories:

```
/web/wiki/templates/wiki.domain.com
/web/wiki/templates
```

Answer (score 1):

[default_template_handler](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.default.template.handler.func.tpl) is a callback that is called if a template could not be found. Some "examples" can be found in the [unit test](http://code.google.com/p/smarty-php/source/browse/trunk/development/PHPunit/DefaultTemplateHandlerTests.php)

Comment: +1 - Didn't know about this method, it seems like this would be a good solution instead of checking an array with template names using `template_exists`

Answer (score 1):

From [Smarty Docs](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.set.template.dir.tpl), try:

```
// set multiple directoríes where templates are stored
$smarty->setTemplateDir(array(
    'one'   => './templates',
    'two'   => './templates_2',
    'three' => './templates_3',
));
```

Comment: As for the priority, './templates' will receive highest, if a template is not found , it will search in './templates_2' & then in './templates_3'

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set priority on different templates, but I'm not sure. What you could do is to check if a specific template exists:

```
// check for if a special template exists
$template = 'default.tpl.php';
if ($smarty->template_exists('example.tpl.php')) {
   $template = 'example.tpl.php';
}
// render the template
$smarty->display($template);
```

Comment: Nice approach, I'll try this. I think I'll also try my approach and see if I can set multiple template directories, and then I'll see which one takes priority, if I can. (I didn't try myself yet.)

Comment: @bodacydo - Let me know if you find out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Krister's code, if you have lots of possible templates:

```
$possibleTemplates = array(
    // ...
);

do {
    $template = array_shift($possibleTemplates);
} while($template && !$smarty->template_exists($template));

if(!$template) {
    // Handle error
}

$smarty->display($template);
```